# How to set maximum Image selection limit while pickup image from Gallery in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have implemented multiple image selections from the gallery. However, I want to limit the user to select max 5 images from the gallery.

```
  TextButton(onClick = {
            scope.launch {
                uploadImageLauncher.launch("image/*")
            }
        }
```

Comment: i iterate through the first five uris returned only and add a toast to notify user of this limit. I don't think there is a way to do this on the intent request level.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already done this, I need to know if any option to do it at the Intent level.

Comment: "I have implemented multiple image selections from the gallery" -- your question should have a [mcve] showing what you are using.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, I am using Jetpack compose and launcher for launching the picker, let me add the code.

Answer (score 5):

You have not specified what `launcher` is.

If you use [the new `PickMultipleVisualMedia` launcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia?hl=en), you can specify `maxItems` to attempt to limit the number of selections. However, that request will not be honored on all devices, and you will need to check your results to see how many items you get back.

Comment: How can set maxItems in every call this launcher? I can not change max items count.

Comment: @AhmetYılmaz: You could have different launchers for each distinct max items count. Personally, I have not had to deal with this issue, so I have not worked out a solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately, applying limit to gallery images selection is not possible via inbuild methods. You have to apply some condition is your code, like below:

```
if(imagesArraylist.size() == 10) {
      Log.e("Show pop-up OR toast msg ", "that you have exceeded selection limit");
} else {
// do something relevant to handle else condition
}
```

> Assuming imagesArraylist is where you are adding the images URI which are selected from gallery.

Answer (score 0):

When you set ***"maxItems"***, you cannot go beyond this number.

```
val multiplePhotoPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(maxItems = 10),
        onResult = { uris -> selectedImageUris = uris }
    )
```

It worked for me.